# Order of TestExecutionListeners

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = LoadBalancingIntegrationTest.class, mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class LoadBalancingIntegrationTest extends AbstractTestExecutionListener{

    //...

    DummyWebAppService[] dummyWebAppControllers = new DummyWebAppService[4];

    int haproxyListeningPort = 8000;

    //DummyWebApp
    @Value("${dummyWebApp.mvnPath}")
    String mavenPath;

    @Value("${dummyWebApp.webAppPath}")
    String webAppPath;

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        dummyWebAppControllers[0] = new DummyWebAppService(mavenPath, webAppPath, 8080);
    }

    //..test cases follow
}
```

I am using spring dependency injection in my test case. I have an issue with the order of execution of the TestExecutionListeners. According to [this documentation about the ordering of custom TestExecutionListeners](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html), the order can be specified via the Ordered interface or @Order annotation, and [by default, the order is of lowest predence for any custom TestExecutionListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html). However, when executing this test class, beforeTestClass is executed before any injection. I even put in `mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS` so that no default `TestExecutionListeners` would be missed. When commenting out beforeTestClass, injection executes as normal.

My question is, why is my beforeTestClass being executed first? Can I tell it to execute after injection?

Comment: Wait, is this class supposed to be a test or an execution listener? You're mixing concerns.

Comment: @chrylis I'm just using TestExecutionListener to setup a beforeTestClass method so both, I don't see why I should refactor it out right now, I'll do so after

Comment: Maybe to clarify, my problem is not that the methods or dependency injection is not working, they are, but in the wrong order. Depenedency injection should occur first and then the beforeTestClass method.

Comment: That will not work because your test is the testexecutionlistener. The problem is the mixing of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the right fix but it is enough for my use case, which is inject beans before the beforeTestClass. Just force it to autowire by writing
`@Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        testContext.getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
        dummyWebAppControllers[0] = new DummyWebAppService(mavenPath, webAppPath, 8080);
    }`

Seems a bit hacky to force autowire but hey my problem is solved

Comment: What you are doing is already hacky imho. You have a `TestExecutionListener` which is also a test itself. That is not something you should do. To get the properties you should be using the `Environment` and not `@Value`. Also what you are doing here is hardly a case for a `TestExecutionListener` and can easily be achieved with a simple setup method annotated with `@Before`.

Comment: @M. Deinum I was not clear with my intentions for the setup of this test class. It is an integration test where I start up various dummy web apps which takes a long time to start up hence not using `@Before`. I wanted to use `@BeforeClass` but JUnit insists they be static of course. Now I run into the problem where Spring does not allow me to inject static objects. Hence this `beforeTestClass` method. Also I don't understand the need to use `Environment`? [This post says otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897314/differences-between-value-annotation-and-the-environment-api)

Comment: That way you don't need the `@Value`, you can just use `testContext.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment().getProperty()` that way you can remove your hack... But as stated the real problem is the fact you are mixing concerns here.

Comment: I wonder why aren't you simply creating a `@Configuration` and create those beans/instances there? If you need them in your test that would be the proper way without the hack of a `TestExecutionListener`.

Comment: You're right, I should just use a @Config.. still learning Spring here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @M.Deinum The `@Value` is probably fine with the Spring runner, it's just all the other organizational bits.

Comment: Not for a `TestExecutionLIstener` that won't be auto wired.