# Difference between Autowired Environment and EnvironmentAware

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Doing a Spring Application with multiple Components (to access a property deeper in the code)

- the Main one Spring BootApplication

  - a dispatcher Component

    - a main prototype Component

      - a client prototype Component
      - a server prototype Component

everything below main is a Runnable too for better Thread handling.

because the client and the server one are created by the main one which is created by the dispatcher one, the main and dispatcher are already ApplicationContextAware.

now the thing is that i need to access Environment inside of client and server.
First i did it via @Autowired, then i noticed EnvironmentAware.

What are the Pro and Cons of using them or isn't there much of a difference in my case?

Comment: please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897314/differences-between-value-annotation-and-the-environment-api

Comment: Ignoring the applicationContext specific parts, question "[Best Practise of injecting applicationContext in Spring3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9657961/5221149)" has good answer for `xxxAware` vs `@Autowired`. Essentially, there is no difference, so use whichever seems clearer to you.